# Find same Id from two grid

Tags: extjs

hello i am have two grids and i transfer records from first grid (book with field: id, author,price) to second grid (discount with field: id, author, price, new price ) with drag and drop, all good, but i am want next: when i am drag record from grid (book) and drop to grid (discount) i am want find record with same Id  and output to console:

i am find 'Id' from grid (book)

```
beforeDrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {
Ext.each(data.records, function(item, index, allItems) {
console.log(item.data.id)}}
```

i am find 'Id' from grid (discount)

```
beforeDrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {
Ext.each(data.records, function(item, index, allItems) {
console.log(overModel.data.id)}}
```

how to find the same 'Id' in the two tables? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in `find` and `getAt` methods.

```
var storeA = Ext.getStore('your.first.store');
var storeB = Ext.getStore('your.second.store');
var indexA = storeA.find('id', 1);
var recordInStoreA = storeA.getAt(indexA);
var indexB = storeB.find('id', 1);
var recordInStoreA = storeA.getAt(indexb);
```

More detail in the [Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)